# QuickFixJ app suddenly hangs during Session start. Have I missed something?

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am connecting to an exchange using QuickfixJ, FIX44.

Everything has been running smoothly until yesterday when suddenly during logon, the whole app hangs at and continously tries to reconnect without ANY response from the exchange:

```
SessionTimer Started
java.net.ConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information (Next retry in 5000 milliseconds)
```

The exchange is up, the servers are up. I have not made any code changes.

Though the exchange has a bad habit of regularly making code changes without telling anyone and I'm awaiting a more official response from their side,
I would like to know if there is something I might have missed or tests that I could run on my side.

I'm quite new to programming so please be patient with me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The problem really wasn't on my side.
Exchange changed the API's server IP.

Have a nice day all.